# My local website freeze my raspberry

Tags: javascript, php

I have a Raspberry PI3 with Apache installed. I made a website where I read some outputs commands (4 commands) and I refresh every 50 ms each command to get the exact value in time. I already used flush command but it doesn't change.

This local site just gives me some information in CANBUS from a machine.

But, after 2 hours in the website , the memory usage is nearly full (947732 kiB in total, 874855 kiB used after 2 hours).

Does it because I never erase the memory after I read a value ?

To see approximatly how I read a value in variable_can.php :

```html
<?php
$output = shell_exec("sh r.sh"); // r.sh contains the command
preg_match("/1D000700 +\[2\]\s+\K[A-Z0-9]{2}\s+[A-Z0-9]{2}/",$output,$value);
echo "$value A";
?>
```

in my index.php where I have javascript :

```html
function myFunction(){
$.ajax({ url: 'variable_can.php',
             data: {action: 'variable_can'},
             type: 'post',
             success: function(output) {
              document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = output; // demo is my ID of my variable_can.php
              setInterval(myFunction(), 50);
                      }
          });

    }
    setInterval(myFunction(), 50);
```

Answer (score 0):

It's probably because you run a shell script called `r.sh`, and you never kill it. So every 50ms it'll re-run the shell script.

Comment: It should indeed be a memory issue because of the shell_exec, but why run a script 20 times a second?

Comment: I was wondering the same thing. It should be fine to run this like every minute or every 30 seconds max.

Comment: I need to refresh the variable every 50 ms at least.

Comment: Kill the script before executing again, that should keep the memory from building up.